# System dynamics SEIR infectious curve for 3 waves of Covid

Tags: anylogic

Using system dynamics on anylogic how can you model a simulation that will give an infectious curve of this nature(Below picture) using SEIR.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SilHi.jpg)

I have tried to simulate, however my graph goes up and down. It does not oscillate as per the attached picture.

I need to simulate something similar to the graph for my assingment.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how can I do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Comment: Please show us what you have done thus far.

Answer (score 1):

There should be three types of events in your model.

First, lets call it "initial spread", is triggered on the start of your simulation.

Second, lets call it "winter season", is triggered annualy in November\December.

Third, lets call it "mass vaccination" - you can decide when to trigger it and for what selection of your agents.
So first two are kind of global events, and the third event is specific to some sub-population (this can make the third wave kind of "toothy" if you  trigger it in slightly different moments for different populations).

That is pretty it.

Curios to see how your model will predict the fourth wave - second winter season of your simulation. So keep us updated :)

Comment: Generally agree but the questioneer asked for System Dynamics. This helps for an agent-based model :)

Comment: @Benjamin right, ive wrote it and then realised that i had AB in mind. But as far as i know you can also have events in SD and different countries can be simulated as different stocks i suppose.

Comment: Absolutely. Thx for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to model this. One of the simplest ways is to simply use a time aspect for one of your infection rate parameters so that the infection rate increases or decreases with time.

See the example below.

I took the SIR model from the Cloud https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/d465d1f5-f1fc-464f-857a-d5517edc2355?mode=SETTINGS

And simply added an event to change the Infectivity rate using an event.

[image]

Changing the chart to only show infected people the result now looked something like this.

[image]

(See the 3 waves that were created)

You will obviously use a parameters optimization experiment to get the parameter settings as close to reality as possible